# Dynamic programming - Evaluating grid size

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I was reading dynamic programming problem, 0/1 knapsack at https://www.educative.io/courses/grokking-dynamic-programming-patterns-for-coding-interviews/RM1BDv71V60

Upon reading, Question I have is, which is a general question,

If I straightaway want to jump to a bottom-up approach, how do we finalize the storage grid size to start within a bottom-up approach? I mean in the given example of the link, recursive/brute force solutions have two variables changing. That is why I believe, that 2D grid size come into the picture and from there I reached top-down and then bottom up. How would you think of the dimensions of the storage grid if I want to jump to bottom-up approach directly.

And how do we decide which dimension represents what?

It would be excellent if someone can shed light on it. I would be happy to add more details if needed.

Comment: I read a very similar problem recently. Yesterday I think. Was that question also by you?

Comment: @Yunnosch, Yes. They asked me to edit the question and post it again. :) They closed that probably.

Comment: Must be deleted, I do not find it anymore. Note, if you are not very sure that you can fix all the problems a question was closed for, then editing the old one is better for you than deleting it. It is hence rare/unlikely that deleting and reposting is recommended to a questions author.

Comment: @Yunnosch, Thanks for the concern. I edited it more and posted it again here.